# REST API: Customize recipient name when using messageDefinitionSends

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I'm attempting to send messages using the REST endpoint:
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:[my_send_key]/send

I've set a "Name" property of the "To" element:

```
{
    "To": {
        "Address": "acprecipient1@nedr.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "acprecipient1@nedr.com",
        "Name": "Recipient Name One",
        "ContactAttributes": {"SubscriberAttributes": {
            "CustomSubject": "Some Custom Subject - SoapUI 1",
            "CustomBody": "<p>Some Custom Body Content - SoapUI 1<\/p>"
        }}
    },
    "From": {
        "Address": "acpsender@nedr.com",
        "Name": "Sender Name"
    }
}
```

The messages are delivered, but the recipient name is not set.

```
From: "Sender Name" <acpsender@nedr.com>
To: <acprecipient1@nedr.com>
Subject: Some Custom Subject - SoapUI 1
```

I've sent the Address pre-formatted with the name, but those messages are never received.

```
{
    "To": {
        "Address": "\"Recipient Name Two\" <acprecipient2@nedr.com>",
        "SubscriberKey": "acprecipient2@nedr.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {"SubscriberAttributes": {
            "CustomSubject": "Some Custom Subject - SoapUI 2",
            "CustomBody": "<p>Some Custom Body Content - SoapUI 2<\/p>"
        }}
    },
    "From": {
        "Address": "acpsender@nedr.com",
        "Name": "Sender Name"
    }
}
```

I've also tried to set the name in a contact attribute.

```
{
    "To": {
        "Address": "acprecipient3@nedr.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "acprecipient3@nedr.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {"SubscriberAttributes": {
            "Name": "Recipient Name Three",
            "CustomSubject": "Some Custom Subject - SoapUI 3",
            "CustomBody": "<p>Some Custom Body Content - SoapUI 3<\/p>"
        }}
    },
    "From": {
        "Address": "acpsender@nedr.com",
        "Name": "Sender Name"
    }
}
```

Those messages are delivered, but the name is still not set.

```
From: "Sender Name" <acpsender@nedr.com>
To: <acprecipient3@nedr.com>
Subject: Some Custom Subject - SoapUI 3
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
From: "Sender Name" <acpsender@nedr.com>
To: "Recipient Name Three" <acprecipient3@nedr.com>
Subject: Some Custom Subject - SoapUI 3
```

Is this possible with the REST API?

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, ExactTarget never populates a a recipient name in the SMTP header. So I am not sure if this a limitation of the API, or the system itself.

Comment: Looking into if this is possible - but so far I come up empty.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're able to include the name on the recipient.  Reading through [this documentation](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/messaging/messageDefinitionSends.html), I don't see an option to specify name on the TO field.